# Meteor helpers generate error when not in client part

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I have run into ReferenceError only to discover that I need to put template helpers in isClient check. I do not understand why it cannot be put in common server/client part and why Isobuild generates such error. As I am beginner I would like to grasp why "`if (Meteor.isClient)`" is absolutely necessary here?

leaderboard.js

```
if (Meteor.isClient){
Template.leaders.helpers({
    players: function () {
        return "Result";
    }
    });
}
```

leaderboard.html

```
<head>
    <title>Leaderboard</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Leaderboard</h1>
    {{> leaders}}
</body>

<template name="leaders">
    {{players}}
</template>
```

Comment: The original error was ReferenceError: Template is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In danger of stating the obvious, templates don't exist on the server. Blaze is currently client-only. It doesn't not allow server-side rendering ([yet](https://trello.com/c/Lz07fBAm)?).

Note however that in any larger project, you would be putting your client code in the `client/` subfolder anyways, and there you don't need to guard that code with `if (Meteor.isClient)` anymore.

Comment: Thanks! I only wish Meteor error codes would be more understandable for beginners.